# The following character ``[`` isn't working in table, error : ! Paragraph ended before \CT@rowd was complete. \par

Tags: tables, r, markdown

I'll ask my question here since I think it has more to do with **LaTeX** than **stackoverflow**. I am using R Markdown with LaTeX to create pdf documents that shows some tables. Using the R language with Markdown and LaTeX is a bit tricky. I currently want to display a table similar to this one :

```
Age         Womens         Mens          Total
1: [20,30)    179,0 (2,4)    118,0 (2,0)    297,0 (2,2)
2: [30,40) 2 325,0 (30,9) 2 115,0 (35,4) 4 440,0 (32,9)
3: [40,80) 1 814,0 (24,1) 1 610,0 (26,9) 3 424,0 (25,4)
...
```

The LaTeX version of this table have the **booktabs** and **striped** options.

The problem is that when I knitr (run the code), `[` is causing the following error :

> ! Paragraph ended before \CT@rowd was complete.  
>                      \par

I know this is the problem since when I changes `[` by `(` I got no problem and my table is showing up without any problems but I have to use it for this document `[`.

The R package I use for LaTeX is `kableExtra` which convert my table into LaTeX code (which gives an error), the code with a problem is :

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
Age & Womens & Mens & Total\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{gray!6}  [65,70) & 179,0 (2,4) & 118,0 (2,0) & 297,0 (2,2)\\
[70,75) & 2 325,0 (30,9) & 2 115,0 (35,4) & 4 440,0 (32,9)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  [75,80) & 1 814,0 (24,1) & 1 610,0 (26,9) & 3 424,0 (25,4)\\
[80,85) & 1 226,0 (16,3) & 939,0 (15,7) & 2 165,0 (16,0)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  [85,90) & 1 033,0 (13,7) & 745,0 (12,5) & 1 778,0 (13,2)\\
\addlinespace
[90,95) & 609,0 (8,1) & 343,0 (5,7) & 952,0 (7,1)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  [95,100) & 253,0 (3,4) & 96,0 (1,6) & 349,0 (2,6)\\
[100,109) & 82,0 (1,1) & 15,0 (0,3) & 97,0 (0,7)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  Total & 7 521,0 (100,0) & 5 981,0 (100,0) & 13 502,0 (100,0)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Anyone knows why `[` isn't making my table displaying? I already searched here and on stack without finding similar questions. Also `[` doesn't seems to be an escaping character in LaTeX. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit :

```
Age Womens Mens Total
[65,70) 179,0 (2,4) 118,0 (2,0) 297,0 (2,2)
 [70,75) 2 325,0 (30,9) 2 115,0 (35,4) 4 440,0 (32,9)
[75,80) 1 814,0 (24,1) 1 610,0 (26,9) 3 424,0 (25,4)
 [80,85) 1 226,0 (16,3) 939,0 (15,7) 2 165,0 (16,0)
[85,90) 1 033,0 (13,7) 745,0 (12,5) 1 778,0 (13,2)
 [90,95) 609,0 (8,1) 343,0 (5,7) 952,0 (7,1)
[95,100) 253,0 (3,4) 96,0 (1,6) 349,0 (2,6)
 [100,109) 82,0 (1,1) 15,0 (0,3) 97,0 (0,7)
Total 7 521,0 (100,0) 5 981,0 (100,0) 13 502,0 (100,0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

**Edited for the correction of alignment** of first column ... But sure there is a better way..

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll}
\toprule
{ }Age & Womens & Mens & Total\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{gray!6}{ }[65,70) & 179,0 (2,4) & 118,0 (2,0) & 297,0 (2,2)\\{}
[70,75) & 2 325,0 (30,9) & 2 115,0 (35,4) & 4 440,0 (32,9)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  { }[75,80) & 1 814,0 (24,1) & 1 610,0 (26,9) & 3 424,0 (25,4)\\{}
[80,85) & 1 226,0 (16,3) & 939,0 (15,7) & 2 165,0 (16,0)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  { }[85,90) & 1 033,0 (13,7) & 745,0 (12,5) & 1 778,0 (13,2)\\
\addlinespace{}
[90,95) & 609,0 (8,1) & 343,0 (5,7) & 952,0 (7,1)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6}  { }[95,100) & 253,0 (3,4) & 96,0 (1,6) & 349,0 (2,6)\\{}
[100,109) & 82,0 (1,1) & 15,0 (0,3) & 97,0 (0,7)\\
\rowcolor{gray!6} {} Total & 7 521,0 (100,0) & 5 981,0 (100,0) & 13 502,0 (100,0)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**Explanation:** I added some `{}` in order that LaTeX will realize that the upcomming `[` is not starting an optional argument for the vertical space that would be added (or removed) after the command `\\` (like `\\[+1cm]` etc)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. Your code seems to be good but I still get the same error. Could a LaTeX package cause such errors?

Comment: Are you sure you copy-pasted  the code as it is? If yes... please add a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578) that will give this error with my code...

Comment: Yes I copy-pasted the code as it is, but it didn't work since ``R`` need one more ``\`` to escape the character, so I added ``\`` and it still didn't work. I'll take a look at your link, thank you.

Comment: Thanks I got your code to work, the problem was not the LaTeX. Only one small thing, the rows of the first column aren't aligned, how can I align them? I'll post an example in my question. I guess the ``{}`` are spacing the characters.

Comment: @Gainz ... See edited version ... but wait for better answers too because I didn't realised that problem and haven't really found an efficient solution...

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll accept your answer, anyway the real problem is that ``kableExtra`` seems to have a few errors when some characters are input.

Comment: Thanks @Gainz ... I will ask a question later if nobody add another answer here and will update my answer if we find the "correct" way

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be looking too!